# Slow initial response time when website has been idle?

Tags: cache, performance

I noticed my Craft website is slower to load when it has been idle for awhile. It can take up to 3-4 seconds for the first load, and then it goes down to about 500ms (which is fine) after the first page. I'm also using cache so I could get my query count to about 20-30 per page. I have other websites (non Craft) on the server that are fast to load even when they have been idle for awhile. Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You mention you're using cache, which could mean a whole lot of things, but the symptoms you're describing are typical of what you'd see if you're doing some heavy-handed things inside of a [{% cache %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache), you let that expire, then you're the first person to hit the page when the cache has to rebuild.

That `{% cache %}` tag, by [default](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#cacheDuration), will purge its cache every 24 hours unless you've specified otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Yes when the cache expired it goes up quite a lot (100 queries to build the 3 level nav menu), but it can happen multiple times within 24h. I should find a way to optimize this nested menu instead.

Comment: Maybe you've got other levels of caching going on as well and they're expiring (Varnish, PHP opcache, etc.)